# HTML E-Mail Template with str_replace

Tags: php, html, templates, phpmailer, str-replace

I have a form, which i have programmed with AngularJs. When the user submits
that form a php script (made with Slim) gets executed, which inserts the formdata into the DB and generates an E-Mail (PHPmailer).

Now to the question:

I get the structure from the email with file_get_contents from a template and replace the placeholders with str_replace.

template:

```
<h2>User Information</h2>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Firstname:</th><td>%firstname%</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Lastname:</th><td>%lastname%</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<h2>Other Information</h2>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Phone:</th><td>%phone%</td></tr>
    <tr><th>E-Mail:</th><td>%email%</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Organisation:</th><td>%organisation%</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is that not all of these fields are required and i want to delete
the whole table + the heading if none of these variables (phone, email,
organisation) is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "hide" the table, instead of remove.

Setting a parameter, like:

```
<table style="display: %display-other-information%">
```

If your properties are null, you have to set "none", if not, set "normal".

The better solution, is to create other templates, but, if you don't want, you can do this, like I said.

Answer (score 2):

Best if you create 2 different templates, with and without that table, and render one of them according to the existence of phone, email and organisation.

Something like:

```php
function render($firstname, $lastname, $phone = null, $email = null, $organisation = null)
{
    $templatePath = (is_null($phone) && is_null($email) && is_null($organisation)) ?
    '/path/to/your/template/withought/the/contact/table.html':
    '/path/to/your/template/with/the/contact/table.html';

    $templateContent = file_get_contents($templatePath);

    $placeHolders = [
       '%firstname%',
        '%lastname%',
        '%phone%',
        '%email%',
        '%organisation%',
    ];

    $values = [
        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $phone,
        $email,
        $organisation,
    ];

    $rendered = str_replace($placeHolders, $values, $templateContent);
    return $rendered;
}
```

Comment: Is there a more simple solution to this? I don't want to use this, because i would have to make around 8 templates for this email. (the example shown is not my real template :)

Comment: I think this simplest aproceh out of your three options (me thinking). 1. Having two templates (suggested). 2.Have a template and a partial for the phone, email and organisation to be injected into the template if required (which is another neat solution)  3. Manipulating the content of a single template based on phone, email and organisation state (which is not gooood). :)

Comment: No for such small example, but if your project going to use more templates you might want consider some template engine such as [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)